# Error - cannot encrypt notesdocument when instantiated by notesuidocument

Tags: lotus, lotusscript

I get the error "cannot encrypt notesdocument when instantiated by notesuidocument" at the line `cjDoc.Encrypt`. Can someone tell me how to fix/why it is happening.

```
Dim currDb as NotesDatabase
Set currDb=session.CurrentDatabase

Set cjDoc = currDb.GetDocumentByUNID(Trim(Source.Document.CJ_UNID(0)))   

If Not cjDoc Is Nothing Then 
     Dim parleyRtItem As NotesRichTextItem 
     Set parleyRtItem = New NotesRichTextItem(cjDoc,CJ_PARLEY_LINK) 
     Call parleyRtItem.AppendDocLink(parleyDoc,"Credit Jacket Parley") 

     cjDoc.ParleyUNID = Source.Document.parleyUNID 

     'cjDoc.parleyCreation = "Parley document created " & Cstr(Today) & " : " 

     cjDoc.parleyCreation = "Parley document created " & Cstr(Today) & " " 

     cjDoc.Encrypt

     Call cjDoc.Save(True,True) 
End If
```

Comment: You need to add the code what currDb is defined as.

Comment: Dim currDB as NotesDatabase  Set currDB=session.CurrentDatabase

Comment: what is the context of that code? ie. Where is it executing?

Comment: The flow is as follows:  1. You create a cjdoc by entering the details in it. On saving the document it gets encrypted with a secret key. 2. you click on an action button which opens a memo to send a mail. When the memo is opened, the cjdoc is closed and a parley document is created. 3. Details are exchanged between cjdoc, memo & parley and finally the cjdoc is encrypted from the backend where the error takes place.

Comment: The problem is faced by a user, when she tries to click on the action button "forward" present in the cjdoc document created by some other user. When she creates the cjdoc on her own she doesn't face this issue. She belongs to 2 different groups, 1 having editor & other author access. She has the secretencryption key also. Is there a possibility that the encryption key may not work if you try to encrypt a document created by someone else?

Comment: What if the forward button executes an agent instead of directly running the code. Does the issue still occur?

Comment: The thing is i'm not able to replicate the issue. It works fine for me in the test server and i'm not allowed to do any testing in prod servers. So once i'm able to replicate it in test i could try your solution. I just want to rule out all non code change related options.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you cannot encrypt it while your uidocument is open.

Dit you try closing the uidocument before encrypting?

Comment: Yes the uidoc closes before the memo form opens.

Comment: I had these kind of issues before. Not exactly with encrypting. The thing was in my case that I did the uiDoc.Close() in the same script. Somehow that didn't work out. I had to do the close, record the UNID in a temporary place (Eg the ini-file) and then fire an agent that reads that ID and performs the required operations on the document.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar issues worked around by closing the UI doc, and putting the encrypt code in the Terminate event on the UI doc. Saves working out how to fire the agent.
by the time Terminate runs, the ui doc handle is dropped from memory (which is exactly what you need to happen, so Notes doenst give you the same error) so you have to do the 'make note of UNID and get the backed document afresh" bit that tvdpol suggests.

In queryClose of UI doc, set a temp var with the UNID ..

```
Dim s as new notessession
s.setEnvironmentVar("TempUNID",source.document.universalID)
```

In Terminate event of uidoc, get the UNID and get the original doc, meaning just the backend doc- UI doc is no longer in memory ..

```
Dim s as new notessession
Dim doc as notesdocument
Dim sUNID as string

sUNID = s.getEnviromnentString"TempUNID"
set doc=ds.currentdatabase.getDocumentByUNID(sUNID)

' do encryption  
'
doc.save(false,false)
```